# It seems just impossible to install Ubuntu

Tags: 14.04, partitioning, system-installation

So I had Ubuntu 14.04 installed once on the current laptop, but it froze and wouldn't respond to anything anymore. Since then I've tried to restart the laptop to no success, it just failed to boot. I took the hard drive out and formatted it in Windows Disk Management as I did before and tried a reinstall. I get as far as "Who are you" usually before I get one of the following errors:

```
input/output error during write on /dev/sda

input/output error during read on /dev/sda
```

It seems no matter what I do whether I choose option one or "**something else**" and make the partitions myself, I just cannot get it to install from the disk. How can you possibly brick a blank hard drive like this? I just don't understand.

Please help !

Comment: Sounds more like a bad connection or really a bad hard drive.

Comment: What file system format are you using?

Comment: NTFS file system

Answer (score 1):

What I would do is to try and format the HDD launching Ubuntu from a live CD/USB and run Gparted (should be, but if not available in the live environment just install it sudo apt-get install gparted):

1. Once it is there make sure the disk is not mounted (otherwise can't format it) and select the hdd
2. Toggle Device/Create partition table and create a new msdos table (or whatever is your flavor)
3. Format the disk
4. Install Ubuntu

Not sure if this will work or if your HDD is the problem at all, you should try running a memcheck too or if you have the possibility check with another HDD too.

A.

Comment: Well I followed your steps but I still got the "input/output error during read on /dev/sda" error. I also got an error about the swap partition, "Failed to create Swap space. The creation of swap space in partition #3 of SCSI5 (0,0,0)(sda) failed."

Currently trying to install on another fresh drive. I'll be annoyed if I bricked the first one, WD black brand new. Didn't even think it was possible to do that to a HDD.

Comment: The other HDD worked after installing. So now what could have broken the other HDD?

Comment: @Seven Harddrives often just break, without you doing something. That's why it's so important to have backups! I suggest you RMA it or exchange it for a new one. You can read more about HDD reliablity [here](http://www.pcworld.com/article/2089464/three-year-27-000-drive-study-reveals-the-most-reliable-hard-drive-makers.html) and [here](http://research.google.com/pubs/pub32774.html) if you are interested.